# How to broadcast boolean value to an array

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a Modelica model where I am initialising an array of submodels.
I'm wondering how to best broadcast one value to all array elements. Let me illustrate, only one of the three demonstrated alternatives works without errors/warnings.

```
model test_each_fixed
  model sub
    Real p;
  end sub;

  //sub sub_instance[6](p(start=linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), fixed=true));
  // gives Translation Error Non-array modification ‘true‘ for 
  // array component ‘fixed‘, possibly due to missing ‘each‘.
  
  // fair enough, let's add an "each":
  
  //sub sub_instance[6](p(start=linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), each fixed=true));
  // gives Translation Warning 'each' used when modifying non-array element p.
  
  // damned if I do, damned if I don't?
  // The following works, but is there a better way than an explicit fill()?
  sub sub_instance[6](p(start=linspace(0.0, 1.0, 6), fixed=fill(true,6)));
equation
end test_each_fixed;
```

This is using OpenModelica v1.18.0-dev.beta1 (64-bit)

So, my questions:

- Is the translation warning I get for the second variant an OpenModelica bug, or is this expected Modelica behaviour, considering the error thrown without an `each`?
- Is there a better way to broadcast a `true` to all `fixed` attributes in the array element members?

Comment: I assume it is intentional that `p` is not a parameter, correct?

Comment: Yeah. This is an MWE I tried to extract out of an existing bigger model that I'm trying to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second variant with `each` should work in Modelica; https://specification.modelica.org/master/inheritance-modification-and-redeclaration.html#modifiers-for-array-elements

And I cannot see any better alternatives.

Comment: It does "work", it just generates that warning, not an error. Therefore I'm wondering if the warning is legit and I'm "using it wrong" (i.e. there is another/better way that does not produce a warning), or if the warning is erroneous and should be reported with OM.

Comment: I meant that it should work without warnings; so you are not "using it wrong".

Comment: Thanks, I reported it upstream: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/7777